# Match tempo between two tracks with Logic Pro

Tags: logic-pro

I have a multitrack recording of a song which is a great take, but has no vocals. I have the vocal from a different day. Unfortunately, it's also at a slightly different tempo.

I have tried to use the Flex time tool to make them match manually, but it's proving weird.

It's unclear from the Apple docs what I ought to be doing here.

At worst, I can probably divide up the vocals, and flex tool each line into sounding right, but I'm hoping there's a way to get a lot closer first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Logic so idk the exact method, but a way to try it would be if you can make a stereo mix of the track with vox - track one side, vox the other - import it then use the whole track to line up one against the other. This is probably easiest if you have a drum track you can more easily work with for fast visual line up. You won't need phase-accurate precision for this, as the composite track will be cleared down after.

Each time you make a move, of course the vox track will follow. Once you're happy you could either mute one side & re-centre the vox, or just re-bounce to mono without the instrumentation.